# Scapy scan current website and follow external link

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to do a crawler that able to scan each website it crawls.
The crawler start with the website `example1.com` and do some scan on it.
After it need to left this website with an external link on the current page or another page if there is no external link.
Can someone help me to change my code under to do that ?
Actually the crawler stay on the first domain, crawl lot of time the same domain, and don't follow the externals links.

```
name = "scan"

start_urls = [
    "http://stackoverflow.com"
] 

custom_settings = {
    'RETRY_ENABLED': False,
    'DEPTH_LIMIT' : 1,
    'DEPTH_PRIORITY' : 0,
    'LOG_ENABLED' : False,
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN' : 1,
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS' : 5,
    #'REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE' : 30,
    'COOKIES_ENABLED' : False,
    #'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT' : 20,
    'DOWNLOAD_WARNSIZE' : 0,
    'DOWNLOAD_MAXSIZE' : 23554432,
}

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(),deny=('facebook', 'amazon', 'wordpress')), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
)

def parse_item(self, response):
    request = response.request
    ext = tldextract.extract(request.url)
    domain = ext.registered_domain

    if domain not in domain_visited:
        domain_visited.append(domain)
        print domain

def doScan(self, response):
    .....
```

Comment: What is scan? Your provided code does call `doScan` method on every crawled url. Could you explain a bit better what are you trying to achieve here and what's the problem?

Comment: I would like to scan each domain crawled with this API : http://builtwith.com.
I don't need to crawl multiple page of a domain, I just want to scrape the external links of a page and follow one or more of them.